# SQL Server: Using between with getdate

Tags: sql, sql-server, between

What does the below query mean?

```
CONVERT(date,GETDATE()-1) between d.baslangictarihi and d.bitistarihi
```

I know how to use between by first selecting the column name and then giving the value. but here it is given the value first and then called 2 columns.

Comment: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: All the terms in the expression are scalar values, hopefully d.baslangictarihi and d.bitistarihi are dates. So this is a valid expression which is evaluated for every d row.

Comment: The statement checks if the first value is between second value and third value. You can read about the syntax at microsoft docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets consider a sample data to understand this better.

**membership_dim**

| id | name | dob | membership_start_date | membership_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 19-05-1976 | 01-05-2020 | 31-12-2022 |
| 2 | efg | 10-01-1990 | 21-01-2018 | 31-12-2021 |
| 3 | xyz | 31-01-1990 | 12-01-2022 | 31-12-2022 |

> Your Query

```
CONVERT(date,GETDATE()-1) between d.baslangictarihi and d.bitistarihi
```

rewriting to match the above sample data

```
select * from membership_dim where CONVERT(date,GETDATE()-1) between membership_start_date and membership_end_date
```

> Result set

| id | name | dob | membership_start_date | membership_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 19-05-1976 | 01-05-2020 | 31-12-2022 |
| 3 | xyz | 31-01-1990 | 12-01-2022 | 31-12-2022 |

> Explanation:

lets breakdown the code

CONVERT(date,GETDATE()-1)

-> getdate()-1 = returns yesterday's date in datetime format (*01-23-2022 xx:xx:xx.xxx*)

-> convert = converts the datatime to date (*01-23-2022*)

-> between = a comparison operator

01-23-2022 between 01-05-2020 and 31-12-2022 - returns true

01-23-2022 between 21-01-2018 and 31-12-2021 - returns false

01-23-2022 between 21-01-2018 and 31-12-2022 - returns true

Answer (score 3):

As others explained, this somewhat quirky condition checks whether yesterday's date `CONVERT(date,GETDATE()-1)` is between two date fields `baslangictarihi` and  `bitistarihi`. More importantly, it does so without preventing the server from using any indexes that cover `baslangictarihi`  and  `bitistarihi`.

Indexes are created based on the actual stored values, so applying a function to a field prevents the server from using indexes to speed up searching.

So while `baslangictarihi <= GETDATE()` can use any indexes that cover that field to limit processing only to the matching table rows, `dateadd(d,1,baslangictarihi) <= GETDATE()` would have to process all table rows, calculate the result and compare it against `GETDATE()`. In a large table, this can be very slow.

**SQL Server Date quirks**

The first part has some quirks too, due to SQL Server's somewhat quirky date support. To be fair *all* databases and programming languages have quirks when it comes to dates.

`GETDATE()` returns the legacy `datetime` type which often behaves as a float, with the integral part an offset from 1899-12-30 (no typo, it really is December 30), and the fractional representing time. That's how dates were stored in Visual Basic in the 1990s and Excel ([OADate format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?view=net-6.0))

Since `GETDATE()` acts as a float, it's possible to subtract days by subtracting integers, so `GETDATE()-1` is equivalent to `DATEADD('d',GETDATE(),-1)`.

SQL Server has no interval type, so in some quirky code you'll even see people storing *intervals* as `datetime`, eg `0000-00-01 01:00` and adding two dates directly. None of the "new" date types introduced in ... 2005 (datetime2,datetimeoffset,date) allows this.

Finally, `convert(date,....)` converts `datetime` to `date`, a type that only contains a date. Effectively, this truncates the time part returned by `GETDATE()`

The same expression without quirks would be `CONVERT(date,DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()))`

Comment: "More importantly, it does so without preventing the server from using any indexes that cover baslangictarihi and bitistarihi." Why does the expression that the OP listed (i.e. `CONVERT(date,GETDATE()-1) between d.baslangictarihi and d.bitistarihi`) qualify for your logic re: "applying a function to a field"? They're not applying a function to a field but rather the result of `getdate()` and comparing that to the data stored in the table. I'm probably missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could "explode" the `BETWEEN` expression, such that this:

```sql
CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 1) BETWEEN d.baslangictarihi AND d.bitistarihi
```

becomes this:

```sql
CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 1) >= d.baslangictarihi AND
CONVERT(date, GETDATE() - 1) <= d.bitistarihi
```

This is just checking if yesterday's date happens to be in between `baslangictarihi` and `bitistarihi`, both ends included.

Answer (score 1):

Just understand that everything in a predicate like this is an expression. `CONVERT(date,GETDATE()-1)` means yesterday without the time component. Those two columns are whatever values are on the row that's being considered at the time. You know what it means if there's a column on the left, but this is no different. It gets evaluated just the same.